# Java: Generic accepting only enum types

Tags: java, generics, enums

Assuming that I have a basic enum like:

```
public enum Color { Red, Green, Blue}
```

How can one write a generic class which only accepts "enum classes" so that a concrete instantiation of that generic class might look like `MyClass<Color>`?

**Edit:**

What a actually want to do is to write a generic abstract class containing a function returning all enum "entries"  as list:

```
public abstract class EnumListBean<E extends Enum<E>> {

    public List<E> getEnumList() {
        return Arrays.asList(E.values());
    }

}
```

While `Day.values()` is available `E.values()` is not. What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: No its implementation should not be limited to one concrete enum type but to arbitrary enum types. I just used `Day` to describe more concretely what i want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class EnumAcceptor<E extends Enum<E>> {
    ...
}
```

Use E as a type inside your class.

Answer (score 4):

See Istvan Devai for answer to original question.

For the follow up, methods like `values()` are static methods, so you're out of luck trying to get that from a generic parameter. As a poor solution, you can pass the enum's `Class` object into the constructor. and use `Class.getEnumConstants`. But you might as well pass `MyEnum.values()` into the constructor rather than the class, and so avoid reflection altogether. It's a real shame there isn't a sensible enum metaclass.

Answer (score 1):

An `enum` really declares a class derived from `Enum`. As such, you can use:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Enum> { }
```

Comment: You're mixing generics and raw types.

Answer (score 1):

Note that @Istvan's solution can only accept **elements** of the `enum`, which is fine if that is all you want.

Although you cannot pass the `enum` itself as a parameter (because it does not actually have an object equivalent) you can specify that you must receive the `class` of the `enum` in your constructor and derive the `enum`'s details from that:

```
public class EnumAcceptor<E extends Enum<E>> {
  public EnumAcceptor(Class<E> c) {
    // Can get at the enum constants through the class.
    E[] es = c.getEnumConstants();
  }

  enum ABC {
    A, B, C;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    EnumAcceptor<ABC> abcAcceptor = new EnumAcceptor<ABC>(ABC.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops - duplicate of @Tom's post - sorry Tom :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `E.values()` due to type erasure -- the type of `E` is not available at run-time.

For the specific case in your question, you're probably better off using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Lists.newArrayList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Lists.html):

```
List<Color> days = Lists.newArrayList(Color.values());
```